# How to Block Ultra Surf Proxy Client on Windows

Tags: proxy, firewall, web-filtering

How can I effectively block ultrasurf which is being used on our company network. With ultrasurf all web filters applied on the network are useless. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Ultrasurf is a great program imo, but you can always block its proxy servers. Just remember that if someone is knowledgeable enough to use Ultrasurf they probably know of other ways. For example I put a proxy up on my VPS and use that instead.

Comment: You might want to reconsider blocking ultra surf in the first place. There will always be ways to bypass blacklists. Anyways, for blocking it, @Tech1337's answer should work fine.

Comment: @PlasmaPower, Tech1337's answer though brilliant, will not work well in my situation because the PCs am dealing are not running Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise. The solution for other editions of windows 7 according to the tutorial will work until the person deletes the app and download another one. I checked that myself. I have actually written a batch script that kills the app but i don t know how to make it execute every minute. Any ideas ?

Comment: @dennix2014 How about start->"Task Scheduler"->Action->Create Basic Task

Answer (score 1):

You can easily go ahead and block the file it self so it is no allowed to be run by anyone or everyone based on the rules. You do this through group policy. Here is a short tutorial: http://www.maketecheasier.com/block-specific-programs-in-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks for replying. @Chipperyman573, i heard that the list of proxy servers gets updated by the hour. The info from the tutorial helps until the app is deleted and downloaded again. anybody can delete ultra surf because it doesn't need to be installed. A promising solution will be to write a script that will instantly kill any app listening on port 9666 on the local host 127.0.0.1 but i dont know how to write batch scripts on windows. Any ideas ?

Comment: A much cleaner and less CPU intensive way would be to block all outgoing and incoming traffic on port 9666. This should be easily done by configuring the router. This should be a much better solution than running a script in the background every minute on every computer you want to block this from. I could not reply on the main post since I don't have 50 reputation.